# sort products by calculated factor

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, sorting

I'm trying to calculate a value for sorting a mysql products resultset depending on a "high relevance factor"

With "relevance factor" I mean a calculated value considering:

- views: total views of the product
- purchased: how many time that product is purchased
- customer_purchased: how many time that product is purchased by a customer
- price: price
- qty: quantity available (products with low level stock should have low relevance factor)

Can you suggest some formula to get this value?

Thank you

Comment: Did you just ask us to help in your assignment?

Comment: Hi Sufian, AbcAeffchen below hit target, thank you

Comment: I guess mods will hit a button too, they call it the "vote to close" button. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can basicly use any formular. the question is only if the relecance factor is good enough for your usage.

So this is an examlpe:

```
relevance = a * [views] + b * [purchased] + c * [c_purchased] + d * [price] + e * [qty]
```

Now you have to choose some values for the constants `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` and `e` by considering some rules:

- If a high value of your attribute is good, then the constant should be positiv, else negativ
- The more importent a attribute is, the bigger should the constant be
- If an attribute is much more importent than every other attribute, (and its values are >1) you can sqare the attrivutes value
- notice that some attribute values are much smaller than other ones, so you have to correct this.

so maybe you would choose something like this:

```
relevance = 0.01 * [views] + 2 * [purchased] + 5 * [c_purchased] + -1 * [price]^2 + 1 * [qty]
```

Reasons:

- I think there will be much mor views than purchases, So I want to scale them down. If i do not, the relevance will basicly reflect the number of views.
- The other attributes have values of the same size (let 10 and 500 be of the same size, but not 10 an 1000 or 10000), so the constants will be of the same size.
- I supose purchased as less relevant than customer_purchased, so I choose 2 and 5 as constant factors
- a low price is very relevant, so I have to choose a negativ number and I squared the price, so a very big price will reduces the relevance much more than a small price.

You will have to choose your own constants, since I just choose any constants without information about the expected values of the attributes.

I hope this helps

Comment: very interesting reply, I think I'll play with single factors to get what meets my need. Maybe I can invert importance of purchased and c_purchased, otherwhise a customer could see products he already bought. Thank you